# Need code for look up and approximate function in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, lookup

I am using excel to do some mechanical design work in AutoCAD Inventor.
Excel will calculate the part thickness based on the inputs. I need to look up to see the closest (need to be lower than the calculated thickness) 1/64th value for an inch equivalent as a standard available thickness and input that thickness into another cell.

For example, in B15 I have calculated thickness as 5mm(0.1968"). I have a column with 1/64" increments from J3:J66. If I check manually, 12/64" (0.188") is what I need. How do I write a formula to this task.
FYI - value in B15 is calculated from another equation.
Inventor will automatically take the values from excel and update the model.

Thank you,

Comment: I would use match() with the 3rd arguments set as 1 or -1, can't think which is greater than or less than but 0 is equal to.

Comment: I am currently using =MATCH(B19,K1:K64,1) formula.
it returns the value 12. which is the cell number. the value I need is in the 12th cell.
How do I return this value to this cell rather than the cell number in the array?
Thank you

Comment: Be careful, match returns the position in the array referenced, not the "cell numb er". If your array (A!:A!%) starts at row 1 then 12 is the cell A12, BUT if you array starts in cell A10:A25, then match returning 12 means cell A22.

Comment: Use the position given by match to drive index().

Comment: Thank you, This works!
=INDEX(K3:K66,MATCH(B19,K3:K66,1))
I couldnt figure out how to make index work with the match function. I was making a typo while writing the function.! 
Thank you all!

Answer (score 0):

1mm is ~2.519686 64'ths of an inch.  So all you need to do is multiply the calculated mm amount by 2.519686 and ignore any decimals, which can be easily done with Excel's `int` command, ie. `int(B15 * 2.519686)`. Using your example, `int(5 * 2.519686)` = 12.

Comment: This one works even better ! Thank you. I could just multiply 12 with 1/64th of an inch and get the desired value. No need for a table to lookup.
Thank you!